# Adding dynamic form field options to FuelPHP model properties

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I'm creating a select form element within FuelPHP's model `_properties` variable:

```
protected static $_properties = array(
    'category_id' => array(
        'data_type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'Category',
        'form' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array()
        )
    )
);
```

I want to set `[category_id][form][options]` to the result of an SQL query, however this obviously cannot be done within the class declaration and I've tried modifying the variable from with `__construct()`, this code is below but yielded errors.

```
 function _construct() {

     parent::__construct();

     self::$_properties['category_id']['form']['options'] = array('a');

}
```

My question is, how do I set the field options to something dynamic using FuelPHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Fuel provides a static constructor called `init` that will allow you to assign static properties.

```
function _init() {

     parent::_init();

     self::$_properties['category_id']['form']['options'] = array('a');

}
```

Comment: Ah! Right, very close, thanks :D. If I keep `parent::_init();` in I get the following error `Error - Invalid method call.  Method _init does not exist. in /Users/beneverard/Dropbox/Business/Web/Projects/Neil White/ER Books/fuel/packages/orm/classes/model.php on line 537`. My model declaration looks like this `class Model_Book extends \Orm\Model {`

Comment: Having looked at the docs it would appear I don't have to call `parent::_init();`... it doesn't appear to be causing my problems when I don't.

Comment: You should only need to have the `parent::_init()` if the model you are `extend`ing has its own `_init()` method. If your parent class does not have one it is safe to ignore.

Comment: Excellent, a fair assumption to make considering I didn't post the model code. Many thanks Uru :-)